# How to process .JS files individually in a synchronously fashion one by one in node js after each one of them have finished their tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I have a set of .js files which perform certain tasks. Id like to process this files individually in a synchronously fashion after each one of them had finished their tasks.

Right now when I run my code all functions perform perfectly, yet in an async way. Im afraid I have also tried with promises (take a look at //FILE parent v2 in code) yet it seems that nonetheless the task being executed in order yet not waiting to be processed one after the other.

I´m pretty sure there must be a basic solution to that issue. yet my programming skills are scarce.

thanks for understanding.

right now my code looks like this:

```js
//FILE parent.js
const cp = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');

//PROCESS1
var child_call = cp.fork("process1.js")

child_call.on("exit", () => {
  console.log("1st funtion finished");
})

//PROCESS2
var child_capture = cp.fork("process2.js")

child_capture.on("exit", () => {
  console.log("2nd funtion finished");
})
//PROCESS3
var child_render = cp.fork("process3.js")

child_render.on("exit", () => {
  console.log("3rd funtion finished");
})


//FILE v2 Promisess parent.js


const async = require('async');
const cp = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');


function addPromise() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var child_call = cp.fork("process1.js")

    child_call.on("exit", () => {
      console.log("1st funtion finished");
    })
    resolve()
  });
}

function addCapture() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var child_capture = cp.fork("process2.js")

    child_capture.on("exit", () => {
      console.log("2nd funtion finished");
    })
    resolve()
  });
}

function addRender() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var child_render = cp.fork("process3.js")

    child_render.on("exit", () => {
      console.log("3rd funtion finished");
    })
    resolve()
  });
}

async function addAsync() {
  const a = await addPromise();
  const b = await addCapture();
  const c = await addRender();
  return a + b + c;
}


addAsync().then((sum) => {
  console.log(sum);
});
```

Comment: You're calling `resolve()` synchronously for each promise. Try calling it from _within_ the `exit` event handler for each process. By the way, `a`, `b`, and `c` are all going to be `undefined` since you haven't passed a value to `resolve()`.

Comment: I just did this <    function addPromise(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var child_call = cp.fork("call.js")

    child_call.on("exit",resolve => {
      console.log("1st funtion finished");
    })

});
}    > @Patrick Roberts  It just  runs the 1st  task. and stops *perhaps I'm doing something wrong, an example could help. I'm still learning

Comment: Just a note; you're requiring `async` but not using the lib anywhere in your code (unless it's not included).

Comment: You need to at least show what both versions of `process1.js` looks like

Comment: @slebetman why? process1.js Is a task that performs correctly on solo. The file is the same in both versions. as so for process2.js and process3.js

Comment: Dear @PatrickRoberts indeed you were right. I had to call resolve*() from within the exit. all

Comment: Sorry, I misread your promise based code. And it looks like you misunderstand what promises do. You're doing `a+b+c` when your resolve is empty (`undefined`) so basically you are adding 3 `undefine`s together which does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

### `require` and `module.exports`

One solution that immediately jumps out is to use `require` instead of using `child_process.fork`. This way your imported code will run synchronously and you will get a direct output returned.

Example:

```js
function add() {
  const a = require('a.js');
  const b = require('b.js');
  const c = require('c.js');
  return a + b + c;
}

// or you can make it more usable
function addModules(...fileNames) {
  return fileNames
    .map(fileName => require(fileName))
    .reduce((total, x) => total + x, 0);
}
```

Do note that you will be **required to export your results from those files** if you wish to use them.

```js
// Do your stuff here:
const x = 42;

// Export it
module.exports = x;
```

### Or you can use [`deasync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync)

Deasync allows you to run a promise synchronously by passing that function to it.

Example:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const deasync = require('deasync');

const fork = deasync(cp.fork);

function addPromise() {
  const child_call = fork('process1.js');
  // now synchronous
};
// repeat as needed

function add() {
  const a = addPromise();
  // ...
  return a + b + c;
}
```

**Note:** `deasync` exposes implementation details of Node.js at the language level and as such shouldn't be used unless other safer solutions don't work for you.

Comment: [deasync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync), the package that synchronized-promise depends on, synchronizes promises without polling, so it's much more efficient. Neither package is something that should be recommended though, as they expose implementation details of Node.js at the language level in order to solve a very simple and common problem. These also won't work if the function returns a promise that doesn't resolve at the correct time (which is currently the issue).

Comment: My apologies @PatrickRoberts I'll fix my answer to reflect this information 